# How is that possible, that n is inversely proportional to both $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$ during refraction?

Tags: refraction

We know refractive index of any material $n = c/v$ where $c$ is speed of light and $v$ is velocity of light in medium.
Therefore,
$$n= \frac{c}{f\lambda}$$
where $f$ is frequency of light and $\lambda$ is wavelength of light in a medium.
Since $c$ and $d$ are constant, $n$ is inversely proportional to $\lambda$.

The Cauchy formula says 
$$n= a + \frac{b}{\lambda^2}$$ 
which implies $n$ is inversely proportional to $\lambda^2$.
How is that possible that $n$ is  inversely proportional to both $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$?

Comment: Can you please rewrite this in variables that are being used in physics? Wavelength is usually denoted by $\lambda$, for instance. Cauchy's equation is simply an empirical polynomial fit of the refractive index data and you are simply missing in your first equation that n is a function of $\lambda$.

Comment: sorry , these symbols are not available in my mobile.
can you please send me correction with normal symbols.

Comment: Is this what you mean? In Cauchy's equation n is not proportional to $1/\lambda^2$, it's just a Taylor series.

Comment: Yes, you may say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $f$ for frequency, we have $λf=c$, which gives us $n={c\over v}={\lambda f\over v}$, not $n={c\over \lambda f}$.

However, we could maybe think of it as *effective* wavelength and frequency, perhaps $\lambda_e$ and $f_e$ and get $n={c\over \lambda_e f_e}$.

Either way, let's use your version of the equation (maybe I made a mistake there), and we get:
${c\over v}={c\over f\lambda}=n=a+{b\over \lambda^2}$

Note that the right side is *not* proportional to $\lambda^{-2}$ because of the leading coefficient. Take out the middle and we get:
${c\over f\lambda}=a+{b\over \lambda^2}$
${c\over f}=a\lambda + {b\over \lambda}$

Extend the equation and we get:
${c\over f}=a\lambda+{b\over \lambda}+{c\over \lambda^3}+{d\over \lambda^5}+...$ $=\sum_{i=1}^{∞}{x_i\lambda^{3-2i}}$

Alternately, if we use my version, we get:
${\lambda f\over v}=a+{b\over \lambda^2}$
${f\over v}={a\over \lambda}+{b\over \lambda^3}$

Which extends to:
${f\over v}={a\over\lambda}+{b\over \lambda^3}+{c\over \lambda^5}+{d\over \lambda^7}+...$ $=\sum_{i=1}^{∞}{x_i\lambda^{1-2i}}$

In neither case do we get a mathematical contradiction, although I don't know enough about the physics to be certain there's no physical contradiction (though I somehow doubt such a contradiction would have gone unnoticed for this long).

Note the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_equation) says the Cauchy equation is only valid near the visible light spectrum (around 800-400 nm as I recall$^1$). It lists the first two coefficients for glass as ~1.5 and ~0.005 $\mu m^2$ (depending on the glass). So we need to graph things around x=0.4-0.8 for those coefficients to make sense. Here's the graph with the red line as $y=a$ and the blue line as $y={b\over x^2}$ -- notice how $a$ dominates at these wavelengths.

[image: Cauchy equation with a=1.5, b=0.005 um^2, y=a, y=b/x^2 from x=0.4um to 0.8 um]

$^1$ It's actually 400-700 nm according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light). Still, close enough.

Comment: yes,a constant is there but it should not makes any effect.

Comment: Look at the difference [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D1%2Fx^2%2C+y%3D1%2B1%2Fx^2+from+x%3D-5+to+5). At large $\lambda$ values, the first coefficient dominates. At small $\lambda$ values, the other coefficients dominate and the function goes to infinity.